# Is there a better way to iterate over this JSON data structure?

Tags: angularjs, json, nested-loops

This is the data structure in question:

```
"EditedArticles" : {
"a3" : {
  "versions" : [ {
        "moment" : "a3",
        "question" : "a3",
        "situation" : "a3",
        "version" : 1
      }, ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently, I am using three for loops to access the properties in EditedArticles.a3.versions

```
var getArticlesByMoment = function (moment,situation) {
            angular.forEach(items, function(article, value) {//items are a1,a2,a3...
                angular.forEach(article, function(versions, value) {//versions is the array containing version for each article
                    var checkfirst=0;
                    angular.forEach(versions, function(version, value) {//version is the version of an article
                        checkfirst++;
                        if (checkfirst == 1 && version.moment == moment && version.situation == situation) {
                            //do something;
                            return;
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        }
```

I want to access the properties inside the versions array for each item (eg. a3) to check if an item has the same moment/situation as a desired one. If there are a lot of items, a1 - a1000, then I think this will take a long running time. There may be many objects in each versions array but I only need to check the first object for a matching moment and situation as the rest of the objects will share the same values for those two properties.

Is there a better/faster way to access these properties? I am using an http GET call to get all the items (eg. a3) in EditedArticles.json

Thank you

Comment: Show us how you're calling this `function` -> `var getArticlesByMoment = function (moment,situation) {` in your view (posting all the relevant code), please (maybe you already have the others "keys" so it will be easy).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to traverse your json object recursivly:

```
function traverse(jsonObj) {
    if( typeof jsonObj == "object" ) {
        $.each(jsonObj, function(k,v) {
            // object or array
            traverse(v);
        });
    }
    else {
        // actual value
    }
}
```